# Prove that for every integer $n\geq 0$, $1+3n\leq 4^n$.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction

> Prove that for every integer $n\geq 0$, $1+3n\leq 4^n$.

Proof:

Let the property $P(n)$ be the inequality 
$$1+3n\leq 4^n.$$
Establishing $P(0)$, we see that $1+3(0)=1$ and $4^0=1$, hence $P(0)$ is true.

Suppose $k$ is any integer with $k\geq 0$ such that $$1+3k\leq 4^k.$$
We must show 
$$1+3(k+1)\leq 4^{k+1}.$$
By algebra, we see $$1+3(k+1)=1+3k+3=(3k+1)+3\leq4^{k+1}=4^k\cdot4^1.$$

Since $1+3k \leq 4^k$ (by the inductive hypothesis) and $3\leq 4^k\cdot4^1$ (for $k\geq0$), therefore
$$(3k+1)+3\leq4^{k+1}.$$

---

I think it's good enough, but I might have overlooked something. Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've put a questionmark above one of the $\le$ signs, like so:

$$1+3(k+1)=1+3k+3=(3k+1)+3\stackrel{?}\leq 4^{k+1}=4^k\cdot 4^1\tag{1}$$

You can't conclude that just because $A\le C_1\le C$ and $B\le C$ we have $A+B\le C$. This seems to be what you used in your proof, but I am not sure.

This is how you could've continued your proof:

Since by inductive hypothesis $3k+1\le 4^k$, we have $$(3k+1)+3\le 4^k+3\tag{2}$$

But $(4^k+3\le 4^{k+1}=4\cdot 4^k=4^k+3\cdot 4^k)\iff (3\le 3\cdot 4^k), \forall k\ge 0$.

So that

$$4^k+3\le 4^{k+1}\tag{3}$$

Now combine $(1),(2),(3)$ and you have that $P(k)\implies P(k+1), \forall k\ge 0$, and you've already shown that $P(0)$ is true, so our proof by induction is done. $\ \ \ \square$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $4^k+3\cdot 4^k\iff 3\le 3\cdot 4^k$?

Comment: @H_T I've put parantheses to make it a bit more clear. I'm claiming that $4^k+3\le 4^k + 3\cdot 4^k\iff 3\le 3\cdot 4^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. It should be : $3(k+1) + 1= 3k + 1 + 3 \leq 4^k + 3 = 4^k + (1 + 1 + 1) \leq 4^k + (4^k + 4^k + 4^k) = 4\cdot 4^k = 4^{k+1}$